# How can i add all images from a local/server directory to array and use the array var on another file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, netbeans

I'm using netbeans 8.0.1 and the php ver is 5.3

I have a php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    lang="en"
    xml:lang="en"
><head>

<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
/>

<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Language"
    content="en"
/>

<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0"
/>

<link
    type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="theme/screen.css"
    media="screen,projection,tv"
/>

<title>
    Slidehow Demo -  - Site Title
</title>

</head><body>
    <noscript>
        <p>
            This slideshow requires JavaScript for full functionality. Please either enable it or use a browser capable of it for the "proper" experience. Below are the images that would have been shown in said slideshow.
        </p>
    </noscript>

    <div id="slideShow">

        <img src="Images/radar000025.Gif" alt="slide" />
        <img src="Images/radar000203.Gif" alt="slide" />

                <?php
$dir    = 'Images';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
?>

    <!-- #slideShow --></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

For the test i'm using only two images:

```
<img src="Images/radar000025.Gif" alt="slide" />
<img src="Images/radar000203.Gif" alt="slide" />
```

Now in this case the images are in a local directory and then i'm using xampp v3.2.1 to start apache server.

But later the images will be reading from a directory on a server in a website like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//$allowed_types="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$) |(\.Gif$)";
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif');
$imageDir = 'files/radar-simulation-files';
/*
    Assumes this .php is being run from the http root on the same
    domain as the desired image files.
*/

    $handle = opendir($imageDir);
    while (($imgPath = readdir($handle)) !== false) 
        if ( in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($imgPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), $allowed_types )) 
            echo '<img src="', $imageDir, '/', $imgPath, '" alt="slide" />';
        closedir($handle);

    ?>
```

I used this to add the images to array variable when the images was on a server directory not local and also when all the code was on the same file.

But now i seperated the code to some files.
I have another file javascript file and i want to pass the array variable from the php file to the javascript file and use it on the javascript file.

How can i add the images in the php file to array variable in both cases when the images are on local/server directories ?

Then how to pass the variable and use it in the javascript file ?

This is the javascript file code:

```
(function(d, w) {

    // user defines

    var
        swapHours = 0,
        swapMinutes = 0,
        swapSeconds = 5,
        swapTotal = (swapHours * 60 + swapMinutes) * 60 + swapSeconds,
        loopSlideShow = true;

    // some handy helper functions

    function classExists(e, className) {
        return RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(e.className);
    }

    function classAdd(e, className) {
        if (classExists(e, className)) return false;
        e.className += (e.className ? ' ' : '') + className;
        return true;
    }

    function classRemove(e, className) {
        if (!classExists(e, className)) return false;
        e.className = e.className.replace(
            new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)'), ' '
        ) . replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
        return true;
    }

    function nodeFirst(e) {
        e = e.firstChild;
        while (e && e.nodeType != 1) e = e.nextSibling;
        return e;
    }

    function nodeLast(e) {
        e = e.lastChild;
        while (e && e.nodeType != 1) e = e.previousSibling;
        return e;
    }

    function nodeNext(e) {
        while (e = e.nextSibling) if (e.nodeType == 1) return e;
        return null;
    }

    function nodePrev(e) {
        while (e = e.previousSibling) if (e.nodeType == 1) return e;
        return null;
    }

    function nodeFlush(e) {
        while (e.firstChild) e.removeChild(e.firstChild);
    }

    function nodeReplace(e, newNode) {
        nodeFlush(e);
        e.appendChild(
            typeof newNode == 'object' ? newNode : d.createTextNode(newNode)
        );
    }

    function make(tagName, child, attribs, parent) {
        var e = d.createElement(tagName);
        if (child) e.appendChild(
            typeof child == 'object' ? child : d.createTextNode(child)
        );
        if (attribs) for (var i in attribs) e[i] = attribs[i];
        if (parent) parent.appendChild(e);
        return e;
    }

    function prevent(e, deselect) {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
        if (deselect) {
            if (w.getSelection) w.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            if (d.selection) d.selection.empty();
        }
    }

    function controlEvent(e, handler) {
        handler();
        e = e || window.event;
        prevent(e, true);
    }

    function clockFormat(value) {
        value = String(Math.floor(value));
        while (value.length < 2) value = '0' + value;
        return value;
    }

    // slideShow functions

    function showCounter() {
        nodeReplace(slideCounter,
            clockFormat(swapCounter / 3600) + ':' +
            clockFormat((swapCounter / 60) % 60) + ':' +
            clockFormat(swapCounter % 60)
        );
    }

    function resetCounter() {
        swapCounter = swapTotal;
        showCounter();
    }

    function makeSlide(newSlide) {
        classRemove(currentSlide, 'ss_show');
        currentSlide = newSlide;
        classAdd(currentSlide, 'ss_show');
    }

    function nextSlide() {
        resetCounter();
        var newSlide = nodeNext(currentSlide);
        if (newSlide) makeSlide(newSlide);
            else if (loopSlideShow) makeSlide(firstSlide);
    }

    function prevSlide() {
        resetCounter();
        var newSlide = nodePrev(currentSlide);
        if (newSlide) makeSlide(newSlide);
            else if (loopSlideShow) makeSlide(lastSlide);
    }

    function slideUpdate() {
        if (swapCounter--) showCounter(); else nextSlide();
    }

    function startSlideShow() {
        resetCounter();
        setInterval(slideUpdate, 1000);
    }

    // slideShow setup

    var
        slideShow = d.getElementById('slideShow'),
        slideCounter = make('div', false, { id : 'slideCounter' }),
        slideControls = make('div', false, { id : 'slideControls' }),
        slidePrev = make('a', 'Previous Slide', {
            onclick : function(e) { controlEvent(e, prevSlide); },
            className : 'previous',
            href : '#'
        }, slideControls),
        slideNext = make('a', 'Next Slide', {
            onclick : function(e) { controlEvent(e, nextSlide); },
            className : 'next',
            href : '#'
        }, slideControls),
        firstSlide = nodeFirst(slideShow),
        lastSlide = nodeLast(slideShow),
        currentSlide = firstSlide,
        swapCounter;

    slideShow.parentNode.insertBefore(slideCounter, slideShow);
    slideShow.parentNode.insertBefore(slideControls, slideShow.nextSibling);

    classAdd(slideShow, 'ss_scripted');
    classAdd(currentSlide, 'ss_show');

    // wait for onload to actually start the countdown

    if (w.addEventListener) w.addEventListener('load', startSlideShow, false);
        else w.attachEvent('onload', startSlideShow);

})(document, window);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in front my eyes.
Just replaced this two lines:

```
<img src="Images/radar000025.Gif" alt="slide" />
<img src="Images/radar000203.Gif" alt="slide" />
```

With the php script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif');
$imageDir = 'files/radar-simulation-files';

    $handle = opendir($imageDir);
    while (($imgPath = readdir($handle)) !== false) 
        if ( in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($imgPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), $allowed_types )) 
            echo '<img src="', $imageDir, '/', $imgPath, '" alt="slide" />';
        closedir($handle);

    ?>
```

Changed the imageDir to 'Images' and that's it it's working for local server when using xampp and when i will upload the files to my host ipage.com i will just need to change the imageDir to 'files/radar-simulation-files' simple as that.